# WKWebView iframe X-Frame-Options is 'DENY'

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, wkwebview, x-frame-options

Im using WKWebView control in my iOS app. I'm loading a web page with iframe on it (iframe source is link to Microsoft Office Online application), but that iframe is empty, and I have error in Xcode Simulator's developer tools:
[image]

But in Safari and Chrome browsers iframe loading normally.
What's wrong with my WKWebView?

Comment: I also have another iframe that loading some different web page, and that iframe is working OK